# Latest 64-bit Flash plugin for Linux

Tags: linux, 64-bit, adobe-flash

I'm using Chromium and a 64-bit version of `libflashplayer.so`.
I was wondering if there's a new version out, but it's close to impossible to find the download for it.

Could someone please give me the link to the latest 64-bit flash plugin for Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: You say you're using a 64-bit version of libflashplayer.so, where did you get it?

Comment: There used to be a blog post by a flash developer, and he compiled the plugin for x86_64. It is not there any more, so I want to find another source, however, the answer is quite conclusive on that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe has recalled the 64-bit Linux version of its plugin due to its security issues, and in "preparation" for the final release.

In short, there currently is no 64-bit Linux Flash plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I don't like the idea of using nspluginwrapper (again), but I guess I have no choice...